# Android audio-streaming issue on version 4.2

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I am building an audio streaming app. Here is the code I use to launch the media player:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://wunh.org:8000/"), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

The code works fine on my Droid phone (Android 2.3.4) - it brings up the phone media player and plays the station...

But it does not work on Nexus 7 (Android 4.2) - both "Google play music" and "Video player" fail with the same error code:

> 12-04 11:49:25.373: E/MediaPlayer(13331): Error (1,-1004)

UPD: here is all related logcat entries:

```
12-04 14:04:21.573: D/MediaPlayer(17933): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
12-04 14:04:21.573: I/AwesomePlayer(128): setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
12-04 14:04:21.583: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(128): connect on behalf of uid 10036
12-04 14:04:21.583: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(128): connect to <URL suppressed> @0
12-04 14:04:21.633: I/ActivityManager(481): Displayed com.google.android.music/.AudioPreview: +83ms
12-04 14:05:24.733: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(128): Request failed with status 4 and os_error -118
12-04 14:05:24.733: I/AwesomePlayer(128): mConnectingDataSource->connect() returned -1004
12-04 14:05:24.733: E/MediaPlayer(17933): error (1, -1004)
12-04 14:05:24.733: E/MediaPlayer(17933): Error (1,-1004)
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

-Dmitry

Comment: hmmm.  looked at source for 4.1  not 4.2 ... grep for that error cd=1004 in java/media packages and in jni/cpp comes up blank

Answer (score 0):

AsyncPlayer? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AsyncPlayer.html

```
AsyncPlayer ap=new AsyncPlayer("Player"); 
ap.play(this, Uri.parse(url), true, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: It does not work - same error:  12-04 14:43:47.853: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(128): Request failed with status 4 and os_error -118

Comment: What is the extension of the audio file?

Comment: If I open that URL with browser, the info on the stream page says "audio/mpeg". I tried both "audio/*" and "audio/mpeg" in my code - same error code. I was told this is "live audio" - not sure what it means and how works on their side....   Thanks!

Comment: BTW I found what "ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(128): Request failed with status 4 and os_error -118" means - it is "request timeout"... It is very sad but I can't make it work on Nexus or Samsung Galaxy because of that...